# How to pass json data from ruby controller to javascript (Rails 6.1)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm trying to pass some json data from my database to front-end so that I can manipulate those with javascript! I started by creating some temporary json data in my `home.html.erb` as follows:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    window.testJSON_data = 
    [
        {
            "name" : "Bill Gates",
            "telephone" : 123456789
        },
        {
            "name" : "Elon Musk",
            "telephone" : 987654321
        }
    ];
    console.log(testJSON_data); /* Works as expected - will print JSON data in console! */
<% end %>
```

The code above will print the correct data and JSON format on the console log. But I find some issues while I try to use my database data with the same approach! I started by passing the correct data to my home controller. The ruby code in the controller below will print all data on the browser page using the `render` function, but obviously that's not what I want to do. So I commented the `render` command and tried to capture these data with my `home.html.erb`

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @data = EmergencyFriend.all
    @jsonData = JSON.pretty_generate(@data.as_json)

    #render json: @jsonData
  end
end
```

I have tried this code which almost prints the data as I want but not as an object. I have also tried these, but none will print data as object:

- `console.log(JSON.stringify('<%= j @jsonData.as_json.html_safe %>'));`
- `console.log(JSON.stringify('<%= j @jsonData.as_json %>'));`
- `console.log(JSON.stringify('<%= j @jsonData %>'));`

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    console.log('<%= j @jsonData %>');
<% end %>

WILL RETURN:

[
  {
    &quot;id&quot;: 1,
    &quot;first_name&quot;: &quot;Emergency Contact&quot;,
    &quot;last_name&quot;: &quot;01&quot;,
    &quot;phone_number&quot;: 150431,
    &quot;email&quot;: &quot;user_01@email.com&quot;,
    &quot;twitter&quot;: &quot;@user01&quot;,
    &quot;created_at&quot;: &quot;2021-06-08T12:20:46.298Z&quot;,
    &quot;updated_at&quot;: &quot;2021-06-08T13:04:28.480Z&quot;,
    &quot;user_id&quot;: 1,
    &quot;country_code&quot;: &quot;CY&quot;,
    &quot;dial_code&quot;: 357
  },
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

I know is something stupid but I have been trying for an hour to find a solution and I cannot! It's either passing the data wrongly or printing the data wrongly, but I do not know which is the case here.

**What should I do to store JSON data from ruby controller to JavaScript?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html_safe` or `raw` method on that string.

```
<%= @jsonData.to_s.html_safe %>
```

Consider also fetching it by ajax request.

Comment: Okay thanks, now an Object is returned that I can work with.

Comment: Is there a particular reason of using an AJAX request? Any references?